# How to make my LAMP use 7.1 instead of 5.6.25 (with Pydio)

Tags: php, apache, centos, lamp, pydio

Following (not a very good) documentation of Pydio 7, I managed to have both php 7.1 & 5.6.25 installed on my CentOS 7.3 LAMP server. Looks like php 5.6.25 is used by the Pydio 7 portal & I need to make it use 7.1.3.

```
info.php 
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

placed in `/opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/html/` says, that 5.6.25 is used.

php -v says 7.1.3 is used :(

Apache in `/opt/rh/httpd24/` is used obviously as `info.php` is opened from there :)

Is there any way to update 5.6.25 to 7.1.3 with all the modules used & keep the config, so Pydio portal will keep working after restart?

Also fix for php -v to show proper version used will be much appreciated! :)

Thank you for your help! :)

Best regards,
Val

Comment: You're better off asking at the official forum.